# Can i use a the msg.sender which is a address to call a function of the contract?

Tags: solidity, truffle, dapps, dapp-development

I am trying to mint a ERC721 token using openzeppilin/contracts. It was working correctly, but later had to change the design. So now i am forced to use the msg.sender who is the minter to call the mint fuction.

I was trying to use msg.sender to call the mint function of a contract, will it work?

```
msg.sender.call.gas(1000000).value(1 ether)(abi.encodeWithSignature("mint(address,uint256)",to,tokenId));
```

It does execute with out any errors, but i cannot get the Transfer event.So i am sure it was never minted.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for a contract to "impersonate" somebody else. The solution provided by OpenZeppelin is to setup your contract with the "minter" role.

Since your token inherit from ERC721Mintable the owner can call `addMinter(contractAddress)`.